# SQL injection - results on the web ui vs. mysql output

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, penetration-testing

I am learning some SQL injection basics. I have a vulnerable application (SQLi Labs), so I can see the source code and trying to figure out how the URL should be parameterized to give back the same result as the mysql interface does. However there is a difference which I can not solve, so please help me.

This is the PHP code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This is the mysql query:

```
mysql> select * from users where id=3--'' OR 1=1;
+----+----------+------------+
| id | username | password   |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | Dumb     | Dumb       |
|  2 | Angelina | I-kill-you |
|  3 | Dummy    | p@ssword   |
|  4 | secure   | crappy     |
|  5 | stupid   | stupidity  |
|  6 | superman | genious    |
|  7 | batman   | mob!le     |
|  8 | admin    | admin      |
|  9 | admin1   | admin1     |
| 10 | admin2   | admin2     |
| 11 | admin3   | admin3     |
| 12 | dhakkan  | dumbo      |
| 14 | admin4   | admin4     |
+----+----------+------------+
```

This is the URL:

```
http://192.168.19.155/sqli-labs/Less-1/?id=2--%20%27%27%20OR%201=1
```

The URL gives me back only one row (which was defined in "?id=2" option) the rest of the query (--%20%27%27%20OR%201=1) is seems to be ignored.

The URL query should give back the whole users table as the mysql interface does. There is no input filtering, so I can not understand why the URL result does not equal to the mysql interface output. Please help me!

Thank you!
Erik

Comment: For a basic injection something like: `?id=2%27%20OR%20%271%27=%271` should do the trick, and is fairly simple. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the comment. `--` is a bit tricky as you can see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-comments.html). Click through to Section 9.6 to see other options for using comment syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) returns information about only one row. You can modify script to get expected response such a way:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```